# Can I declare a broadcast receiver into a separate module than App?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-module

I have two modules in my Android project, one is the default one 'app' and another is a 'sample' module, both modules have their separate manifest files. I wish to define a broadcast receiver and it's code into a sub-module - 'sample'.

My primary assumption is sub-module's manifest will get merged into primary-manifest (of 'app' module) when the app is built. I tried declaring receiver into sample's manifest, but since there is no "<application..." component inside sub-module's manifest, it's giving following error

[image: Hello]

**is this even possible to do ? if 'yes' then how to declare and define a broadcast receiver into a sub-module other than 'app' ?**

Comment: You need to create an `<application>` declaration in the submodule.